# Is $(function () {}) same to $(document).ready(function(){});

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

As title says, I am not sure about  `$(function () {})`

**Test:**

```
$(function () {console.log("one")});
```

And at the bottom of body:

```
 console.log("two");
```

the console prints `two , one`

Does it mean `$(function () {})`  is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){});` ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is easily answered by [*reading the fine manual*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)

Comment: thank you , I am a newer. and I want to post a question , but it always says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.", could you help me , thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just `$(function(){ })` is short-hand.

See the [`jQuery(callback)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) overload documentation.